# How do I use SKAction to move my in game monster vertically

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im a beginner slowly learning how swift and Xcode function, as of now I still have issues with simple things like this:

```
 func addMonster() {

    // Create sprite
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/2, max: size.height - monster.size.height/2)

    // Position the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)

    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(monster)

    // Determine speed of the monster
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))

    // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -monster.size.width/2, y: actualY), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))

}
```

please help me move my monster vertically rather than horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly change "`width`" to "`height`" and "`height`" to "`width`".And define a  `actualX`

```
func addMonster() {

    // Create sprite
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    let actualX = random(min: monster.size.width/2, max: size.width - monster.size.width/2)

    // Position the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: actualX, y: size.height + monster.size.height/2)

    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(monster)

    // Determine speed of the monster
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))

    // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:actualX, y: -monster.size.height/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))

}
```

Comment: okay sorry I edited the code, this is all of it and it might make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Keep unchange the x-coordinate and change the y-coordinate

```
let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: actualX, y: -monster.size.height/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration)
let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent() monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

Comment: @I have tried that however it gives me an error for the "actualX"

Comment: okay sorry I edited the code, this is all of it and it might make it clearer